# How to add minutes to a date inside a loop

Tags: java, loops, date, calendar

I have a date that I want to increase by 15 minutes while a certain condition is met. My problem is that it adds up to 15 minutes just once.
The output per screen would be similar to this operation but with dates.

```
int i = 10;
while (i <= 100){
  i = i + 15;
  System.out.println(i);
}

Screen output

10
25
40
55
70
85
100

My code for the dates is the following

while(hour < hourEnd){

 hour = new Date();
 hour = date.getDate();
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
 cal.setTime(hour);
 cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 15);
 hour = cal.getTime();
}
```

Comment: Create your date before the loop. Currently you create a new date with the current time in every loop and then add 15 minutes to it, but from what i understand only the "add 15 minutes" part should actually be inside the loop.

Comment: You are using troublesome old date-time classes, now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My problem is that it adds up to 15 minutes just once.

you'll need to create the `Date` before the loop begins.Otherwise, it will create a new `Date` at each iteration.

```
hour = new Date();
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

while(hour < hourEnd){
   cal.setTime(hour);
   cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 15);
   hour = cal.getTime();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Avoid legacy classes

Avoid the old legacy date-time classes such as `Date` and `Calendar`. They are poorly designed, confusing, and flawed. The java.time framework was added to Java to replace those old classes.

## Using java.time

Get the current moment for you desired time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdtNow = ZonedDateTime.now( z );
```

Apparently you want to add increments of 15 minutes until reaching the end of the clock hour. Better to think of such spans of time in the Half-Open approach where the beginning is inclusive but the ending is exclusive. That would mean we want to run up to but not including the first moment of the *next* hour.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtNextHourStart = zdtNow.plusHours( 1 ).truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.HOURS ) ;
```

Now loop to increment.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = zdtNow ;
List<ZonedDateTime> zdts = new ArrayList<>( 4 );
while( zdt.isBefore( zdtNextHourStart ) ) {
    zdts.add( zdt );
    System.out.println( zdt );
    // Prepare for next loop.
    zdt = zdt.plusMinutes( 15 );
}
```